# Change specific part of a string to Title or Proper case using regex notepad++

Tags: regex, string, character, notepad++

I'm trying to use a regex expression in Notepad to try and convert the following string:

> Name = CASTFORM-1
>
> Name = CASTFORM-2

Into

> Name = Castform-1
>
> Name = Castform-2

I'm able to find the specific characters I need by using

```
(?<=Name = ).+?(?=-)
```

However on the replace, I can't seem to find the appropriate expression. I've tried using

```
\U\1
```

But with no luck, it ends up removing the entry completely leaving just the "-1".
Is this solvable?

Comment: To lower `ASTFORM` how about [search for `(?<=Name = [A-Z])([A-Z]+)(?=-)` and replace to `\L\1`](https://regex101.com/r/tZ9LOI/1). Regarding your sample: There is no *first* [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) for reference `\1` thus the part is removed.

Comment: Using only *capture groups*: [Replace `(Name = [A-Z])([A-Z]+)-` with `\1\L\2-`](https://regex101.com/r/2w0Z2T/1) could also do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

**Find what**:      `(?<=Name = \w)\w*(?=-)`
**Replace with**: `\L$0`

**Details**:

- `(?<=Name = \w)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a position that is immediately preceded with `Name =`  and a word char
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars
- `(?=-)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a `-` char.

The `\L$0` turns the found matched text into lower case.

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for the quick response, I realised that this wouldn't work if there was another line after that in the same format so I've edited my initial question

Comment: @Nuemio It works fine. Try the solution, I get `Name = Castform-1` and `Name = Castform-2` as result.

Comment: Not quite, see image showing what I entered: https://gyazo.com/70f522a4f155276a09a30e11c1c01c99

Comment: @Nuemio I don't know what Notepad++ you are using, probably it does not support `\K`. So, then use your lookbehind then instead. I edited the solution to a simplified one with the lookbehind.